# CSS animation causes jagged edges

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to use a CSS animation to create a preloader animation for my gallery. When I am applying the CSS code below it looks ok in Chrome, Firefox, but it doesn't look nice in Internet [Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovBQb.jpg) and [Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhXSw.jpg). For your reference here is the original [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVIx6.jpg) - for a demo see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmr8hqhv/14/).

I dug through most articles related to this topic and applied the fixes that seem to make sense (see comments in code), but alas it still looks like crap.

Do any of you CSS wizards have an solution for this issue?

```
div.preloader-container {
    background-image: url('img/preloader.png') no-repeat !important;
    background-size: 20px 20px !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    width: 20px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    /* Attempt to fix it 1 */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
    -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden !important;
    -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden !important;
    backface-visibility:         hidden !important;

    /* Attempt to fix it 2 */   
    outline: 1px solid transparent !important;

    -webkit-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 2s linear infinite;

}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { 
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);  
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { 
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin { 100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you I would start with taking out all the "!important" in your css code. 
From my experience it's not needed if you can de-code whatever it is you're trying to overwrite with the "!important". 

I'm writing this because it looks like you're overwriting a lot in your css. 
When you're not overwriting with the "!important" your code is not only cleaner, but it can also be much easier to fix if there are any issues. 

And perhaps this link can help you a bit out with your pre-loader animation you're trying to achieve: https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/css3-preloader-transition/

Comment: Sorry the !importants are only in there because I was desperate and wanted to make sure that these styles were used without having to spend to much time while debugging. Will take a look at the link you provided - thanks!

Comment: I have just noticed, if the png uses the full size it does not look crappy in Safari (for Windows) http://jsfiddle.net/vmr8hqhv/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my in very specific instance the problem was that re-sizing a 200px image to 20px was handled badly by these browser. As soon as I decreased the size of the png to 40px and resize to 20px with the backgroud-size attribute it works like a charm. Hope that helps other people with the same issue.

Here is a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmr8hqhv/19/) with the solved issue and here is one with the [issue](http://jsfiddle.net/vmr8hqhv/3/) still happening.

```
background-size: 20px 20px;
```

Comment: Nice job figuring this out by yourself!